# Can you use HTML 5 to stream video 24/7 on a website?

Tags: html, streaming, wowza

I've got a website and I've been looking for ways to embed a 24/7 webcast. I've looked at options such as Ustream and Justin.TV however, these do not work on mobile devices, which is what I really need.

I don't have that much knowledge on how streaming works but I've read that the streaming Engine Wowza is another option. I also found that HTML 5 player works cross platform and on any mobile device aswell.

If I were to use Wowza would it work with HTML 5 player? And am I even going in the right path with how I can do this. I also have a home dedicated server for streaming to a cloud wouldn't be required.

I'm very amateur just trying to broadcast my television program on my website for viewing. Any advice would help here. Thanks

Comment: Ustream does have an app for iOS, not sure about Android though.

Comment: I don't really want my visitors downloading an app though. I've seen some websites where the stream can be directly viewable without having to do anything but load up their website.

Comment: Twitch.TV does have an HTML5 player... I assume Justin.TV also does, since they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza can packetize video as http live streaming (HLS) which, although an Apple invention, works on most HTML5-capable browsers except IE11: http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/ . Many players will fall back to using Flash for browsers which don't support native HLS or H.264 encoding. Flash uses http dynamic streaming (HDS) rather than HLS, so you would add that as another packetizer in wowza. (Wowza calls these packetizers "cupertinostreamingpacketizer" and "sanjosestreamingpacketizer" respectively.)

You would then point your preferred HTML5 video player (jwplayer, flowplayer, etc) at the URL http:// your-wowza-server.com:1935/live/yourstreamname/playlist.m3u8 [1]. For Flash fallback in flowplayer you can use the f4m resolver and the http-streaming plugin, as in [the first example here](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/httpstreaming.html), to access the subtly different URL http:// your-wowza-server.com:1935/live/yourstreamname/manifest.f4m. I'm sure something similar applies in players like jwplayer and others.

The main problem with Wowza is how much it costs: for your own server you're looking at around $55 per month per channel [2]. At least during testing, you may find it cheaper to get Wowza on Amazon EC2 devpay: $5/month rental plus an extra couple of cents per hour on your normal EC2 instance costs.

[1] Assuming you're using Wowza's default /live/ application on port 1935
[2] A channel is roughly the number of streams you're sending to the server to be re-broadcast

Answer (score 0):

We developped a custom HTML5 player which we wanted to make compatible with HLS and fragmented mp4 for LIVE events. We started on Zencoder but realize they were not able to do genrate fragmented mp4.

I would like to explore the flash fallback solution and the wowza( probably on AWS)  for the packaging.

Would you be available  to consult on this project?

Answer (score 0):

We use [www.bitcodin.com](http://www.bitcodin.com) for event-based or 24/7 live transcoding and streaming. It generates DASH - which can be playback natively in HTML5 using the [bitdash MPEG-DASH players](http://www.dash-player.com) - as well as HLS for iOS devices. You can find an example here: http://www.dash-player.com/demo/live-streaming/